# How do I convert an image to upload a Spotify profile picture?

Tags: go, encoding, jpeg

I'm setting up an image encoder function where you input an image URL and it returns the ISO-8859-1 version of it. How would I write a function that sends an HTTP GET request to the URL and converts those bytes to ISO-8859-1? The code below is everything I have so far.

```
func grabImageBytes(imageURL string) ([]byte, error) {
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", imageURL, nil)
    res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    } else {
        return body, nil
    }
}
```

other func:

```
func getRandomImage(keyword string) (string, error) {
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q="+keyword, nil)
    req.Header.Add("authority", "www.google.com")
    req.Header.Add("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1")
    req.Header.Add("referer", "https://images.google.com/")
    req.Header.Add("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9")

    res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    var imageURL string

    if strings.Contains(string(body), ",\"ou\":\"") {
        imageURL = strings.Split(strings.Split(string(body), ",\"ou\":\"")[1], "\",\"ow\":")[0]
    } else {
        return "", errors.New("Image not found.")
    }
    req2, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", imageURL, nil)

    res2, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req2)

    defer res2.Body.Close()
    if res2.StatusCode == 404 {
        return "", errors.New("Image not found.")
    } else {
        return imageURL, nil
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean run OCR on the image?

Comment: Exactly what do you want to convert to ISO-8859-1? It doesn't make sense to convert the URL, because that must be in UTF-8. If you converted it, it would either be identical, or the web server would just give you a 404 if you tried to use the result to fetch the image. If you try to convert the binary data, you'll just end up with a garbage file that is no longer a valid image.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Should've specified more in the description, haha. I meant that I wanted to use the URL to get an image and convert that image to ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @DominicSparrow: You are still not making sense. ISO 8859-1 is a character encoding, not an image encoding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Comment: @peterSO I'm trying to make an image URL uploader for profile pictures for spotify. When viewing the post request, the image uploaded from the computer to the desktop app is in ISO-8859-1 encryption. It's strange.

Comment: Again, what are you talking about? ISO-8859-1 is not encryption. This looks like an XY problem. You should instead describe the problem you're having, not what you think the solution might be.

Comment: @peterSO If it's encoded in Base64, why is my post request in ISO-8859-1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim that the Spotify profile picture image is [ISO 8850-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoded/encrypted makes no sense.

What would make more sense is that it is Base64 encoded.

For example,

> [Spotify for Developers: Web API: Upload a Custom Playlist Cover Image](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/upload-custom-playlist-cover/).
>
> Base64 encoded JPEG image data, maximum payload size is 256 KB

---

In Go,

> [Package base64](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/)
>
> `import "encoding/base64"`
>
> Package base64 implements base64 encoding as specified by RFC 4648.

---

Another piece of evidence: "HTTPS requests in UTF-8 format"

> [Spotify for Developers: Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/)
>
> Requests
>
> The Spotify Web API is based on REST principles. Data resources are
>   accessed via standard HTTPS requests in UTF-8 format to an API
>   endpoint.

---

For example. using your Stack Overflow profile picture:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func grabImageBytes(imageURL string) ([]byte, error) {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", imageURL, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    enc := base64.StdEncoding
    img := make([]byte, enc.EncodedLen(len(body)))
    enc.Encode(img, body)
    return img, nil
}

func main() {
    imageURL := `https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-P8ICR-LXoBs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAE04/fVAeB6_nMeg/photo.jpg?sz=328`
    img, err := grabImageBytes(imageURL)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(img))
}
```

Comment: @DominicSparrow:  I have added a simple example to my answer. Follow the link to the package base64 documentation in my answer. There are some useful examples. If you get stuck, post your code in your question.

Comment: I noticed the `` instead of normal "", what's the significance? I am a beginner :)

Comment: @DominicSparrow: raw string literals and interpreted string literals: https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals

Comment: How would I incorporate it into the getRandomImage function i just edited into the question?

Comment: by "it" I am referring to the `` @peterSO